# Log use of deprecated fields in python graphene

Tags: graphene-python, graphql-python

Is there a way to automatically log any queries that involve a deprecated field (i.e. one with a non-null `deprecation_reason`)?

It'd be helpful to help work out whether a deprecated field was still in use or could be properly removed.